# converting iphone to ipad app

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to convert a iphone app to ipad app without adding xib's. Also am having QuartzCore framework so i can't use that "upgrade current target to iPad" option. Kindly tell me now how can i convert my iPhone app to iPad app in a easy way.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want more Xibs? Having the iPhone and iPad versions separate is a huge organizational help for me...

Comment: Why does using QuartzCore prevent you from using the upgrade target feature?

Comment: Is the target upgrading failure an Xcode bug?  The QuartzCore framework (containing Core Animation, etc.) is the same across iOS devices.  It should have nothing to do with the addition of an iPad target or conversion of an iPhone target to a universal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use xib's, the only choice is to convert them, otherwise they will not display correctly under the iPad UI paradigm.

The other option is to create all your views in code instead of using xibs, but using the proper frame size for the current UI paradigm.

Plus, you can use the QuartzCore framework with an iPad xib.